# How to handle a request with multiple parameters on Spring-MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am sending following request that need to be handled by Spring-MVC but it does not.

```
http://localhost:2001/MyProject/flights/find?origin=LAX&destination=WA&departure=&arrival=&return=false
```

**Code**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/flights")
public class FlightController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/find?origin={origin}&destination={destination}&departure={departure}&arrival={arrival}&return={return}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findFlight(@PathVariable String origin,
            String destination, Date departure, Date arrival, boolean return) {
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is not the correct way (or place) to use `@PathVariable`.  You need to use `@RequestParam`.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/flights")
public class FlightController {
  @RequestMapping("/find")
  public String findFlight(@RequestParam String origin
                          , @RequestParam String destination
                          , @RequestParam(required = false) Date departure
                          , @RequestParam(required = false) Date arrival
                          , @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false", required = false, value = "return") Boolean ret) { ... }
}
```

Note that `return` is a keyword in Java so you cannot use it as a method parameter name.

You will also have to add a `java.beans.PropertyEditor` for reading the dates because the dates will (presumably) be in a specific format.

Comment: I see thanks, then when can I use @PathVariable? when they are in /param/param2/param4 format?

Comment: Correct, `@PathVariable` is for when you want to extract information from the request path.  The request path ends at `?` after which request parameters start.

Comment: I even changed the Date to String but does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  Is there an error, are the parameters `null`?  This is the correct mechanism.  See [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam).

Comment: the parameters are not null, it does not call findFlight method.

Comment: That is a different issue altogether.  You will need to turn on debug logging and examine the logs to find why the request is not getting to the controller.  One thing you can do is for the parameters which can be left blank by the user, put `@RequestParam(required = false)`.

Comment: I added that but it does not work. I can call another method of the same controller but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may be it works:

```
 @RequestMapping("/find")
  public String findFlight(@RequestParam("origin") String origin
                          , @RequestParam("destination") String destination,....
```

Comment: thanks the correct answer is already accepted. Do you think the answer is wrong?

Comment: @Jack it gives you another option in case you don't want to name the url parameters the same as the methods parameters.